# How do I archive a trashed message in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

How do I remove a message from the trash without it going to the "Inbox" folder?

If I open a message in the trash, my only options of removing it from there are: pressing the "Move to inbox" button or "Recover from trash". However, in both cases it moves the message to the inbox rather than archiving it, forcing me to have to manually find this email and archive it.

If I try to press "Archive" on a trashed message, it does nothing.

Do I really need to do this two-step process every time I want to archive a trashed message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to archive it with a tag, you can just:

- Click "Move To" -> [Tag name]

Otherwise it seems that two steps is the only way.

Answer (score 3):

Just select move to and select the label you want to move it to.  This will move it to all mail plus also that label.

If you don't have any labels you can just create a new one called "archived from trash" or something like that.

If you don't want it to show up on the main view you can click on the label options (icon next to the label and select hide label).

This will at least save you some time.

Comment: What about if I don't want to label it as anything... are there any other options?

Comment: @eagle: See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm accepting x3ja's though, since it is more terse, and I think it will help people in the future looking for a quick answer.